# Ceasar Cipher in Python, Output trouble

Tags: python, encryption

code:

```py
val = input('Do you want to encrypt or decrpt a message: ')
if val == "encrypt":
    enr = input('Please enter a string: ')
    for c in val:
        if "a" <= c <= "z":
            print(chr(ord("a")+(ord(c)-ord("a")+4)%26), end="")
        elif "A" <= c <= "Z":
            print(chr(ord("A")+(ord(c)-ord("A")+4)%26), end="")
        else:
            print(c, end="")
```

output:

```
Do you want to encrypt or decrypt a message: encrypt
Please enter a string: i love YOU
irgvctx
```

No matter what string I input, the output always becomes `"irgvctx"`

Answer (score 1):

You meant to write:

```py
  for c in enr:
```